# Adding code completion to all of my files in Komodo Edit

Tags: komodo-edit, komodo

I am new to Komodo Edit.

Does anyone know how to add intellisense to my own files?

For example: myFirst.js that includes auto completion for objects or functions that were defined in mySecond.js

Also how do I add auto completion to my CSS file from my HTML file?

Another example: When working with visual studio(Microsoft), I put this statement at the beginning of file2.js :

```
 /// <reference path="../js/file1.js" />
```

and then I had intellisence  for file1.js inside file2.js

I want to do the same thing in komodo-edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Komodo, you add directories to the list of scanned locations, and then Komodo will provide code intelligence (completions/calltips) for these files.

Use the "Edit > Preferences" menu and then navigate to the "Languages > JavaScript" category, adding the "../js" directory to the "JavaScript Directories".